# Django - Find sum and count of values in child table using serializers

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I have two tables: `Event` and `EventTicket`. I have to return total transactions and total tickets sold of each event. I am trying to achieve this using Django serializers. Using only serializers, I need to find the following:

```
 1. total tickets sold: count of items in EventTicket table for each event
 2. total transactions: sum of total_amount of items in EventTicket table for each event where payment_status: 1
```

I read about `SerializerMethodField` but couldn't find a solution specific to this scenario.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    description             = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    date_time               = models.DateTimeField()

class EventTicket(models.Model):
    user                    = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event                   = models.ForeignKey(Event,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment_status          = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, null=False, blank=False) ## payment_success: 1, payment_failed: 0
    total_amount            = models.FloatField()
    date_time               = models.DateTimeField()
```

My desired output is:

```
"ticket_details": [
      {
        "event_id": 1,
        "event_name": Event-1,
        "total_transactions": 10000, ## Sum of all ticket amounts of event_id: 1, where payment_status: 1
        "total_tickets": 24,  ## Count of all tickets that belong to event_id: 1
      },
      {
        "event_id": 2,
        "event_name": Event-2,
        "total_transactions": 10000, ## Sum of all ticket amounts of event_id: 2, where payment_status: 1
        "total_tickets": 24,  ## Count of all tickets that belong to event_id: 2
      }]
```

This is what I have done:

**models.py:**

```
class EventTicket(models.Model):
     event = models.ForeignKey(Event,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='event_tickets')
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class EventListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     # ticket_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')
     # event_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='event', read_only=True)
     # event_name = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='event.name', read_only=True)

     total_transactions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
     total_tickets = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

     class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('total_transactions', 'total_tickets')

     def get_total_transactions(self, obj):
         return obj.event_tickets.all().aggregate(sum('total_amount'))['total_amount__sum']

    def get_total_tickets(self, obj):
         return obj.event_tickets.count()
```

Comment: share something that you tried with solve or any code you have written. the code you shared is doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be like this with `SerializerMethodField`:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    total_transactions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_tickets = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'total_transactions', 'total_tickets')

    def get_total_transactions(self, obj):
        return obj.tickets.all().aggregate(Sum('total_amount'))['total_amount__sum']

    def get_total_tickets(self, obj):
        return obj.tickets.count()
```

Note:
Add related name `tickets` in `Event` Foreign Key in `EventTicket` model:

```
event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tickets')
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the EventTicket instance.`

Comment: You need to add related name, I have updated answer.

Comment: I am still getting this error though: `'EventTicket' object has no attribute 'tickets'`

Comment: Please verify if your using Event or EventTicket Model for serializer?

Comment: I am using the `Event` model

Comment: Can you update your latest serializer in your question?

Comment: I have updated the post for your reference.

Comment: It should be `tickets` not `event_tickets`. Please see my answer.

Comment: I am getting this error though: `'EventTicket' object has no attribute 'tickets'`

Comment: Ah! I have just seen that you are using related name as `event_tickets` so that's fine. On which line you are getting above error?

Comment: The return statements inside the functions is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as `property` in the model like this:

```
class EventTicket(models.Model):
    user                    = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event                   = models.ForeignKey(Event,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment_status          = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, null=False, blank=False) ## payment_success: 1, payment_failed: 0
    total_amount            = models.FloatField()
    date_time               = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def total_transactions(self):
        if self.payment_status:
            return self.event.eventTicket_set.count()
        return -1
```

Comment: Why would `-1` be a return value from this function? Better would be to raise an exception (to show that there is no meaningful total number), with a type chosen to communicate what the reason is.

Comment: Maybe he need to return a response even if payment_status != 1.